# Is there a way to format vue template to have all tag attributes at the same line

Tags: html, vue.js, formatting, phpstorm, eslint

Several iterations ago one of our devs applied --fix with eslint rule vue/max-attributes-per-line on whole codebase so we are having max 1 attribute per line in our vue templates.

Is there any way to format it back?

was trying to use phpStorm format option "wrap attributes": "Do not wrap" but it doesnt work on already wrapped attributes..

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to disable **Keep line breaks** and set **Wrap Attributes:** to **Do not wrap** in **File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Other**